# How to make Windows 7 Virtual Machine get an IP address dynamically from another VM in the same VMware workstation 9

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I am running an instance of VMware workstation 9, in which I have installed Windows Server 2012 as one VM and Windows 7 as another.

I want the Windows 7 VM to get an IP address dynamically from the server 2012 VM, which is also running in same workstation. I have configured DHCP, DNS, and AD. AD is working fine. But DHCP is not working: my Windows 7 machine is not getting an address dynamically from specific scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Host-Only adapters and bridge them together with Windows Bridge mechanism.

Then switch off built-in VMware DHCP server.

1. Run `VMware Virtual Network Editor` with following command:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\vmnetcfg.exe
   ```

   OR

   ```
   rundll32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\vmnetui.dll",VMNetUI_ShowStandalone
   ```

   (in some installations there is no vmnetui.dll / vmnetcfg.exe - in that case you can extract it from VMware Workstation installation file using "/e" switch)
2. Select VMnet1 and click `DHCP Settings...` and un-tick DHCP Server.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use one of the unused VMnets, like VMnet4 or whatnot. They have no DHCP, bridging or host-only adapter configured by default.

All virtual machines connected to a specific VMnet can talk to each other as if they were connected by a switch.

If you need your host OS to be able to access this virtual network, you can add a host-only network adapter in Virtual Network Editor.